# How can i affect more than one class on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to affect element's display,color or something when i hover a element.Class names can be different. Will not always contain sub.

Example:

```css
.main{
  background:yellow;
  display:inline-block;
}
.sub{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  opacity:.2;
}
.sub2{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  opacity:.2;
}
.main:hover .sub,sub2{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='sub'></div>
    <div class='sub'></div>
    <div class='sub'></div>
  <div class="sub2"></div>
</div>
```

I can do it like that but its look like dublicate.If i can do it will save 30 lines of code. Can i do it at once. Is it possible?

```css
.main:hover .sub{
  opacity:1;
}

.main:hover .sub2{
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `.sub:hover { opacity: 1 }`?

Comment: Apparently he wants the effect to happen when he hover over main class and not sub class.

Comment: @M.AShahbazi some of the elements below will close but some will not. I don't want affect all.

Comment: I believe, you want to find shortest solution and using [class^=sub] looks shortest selector to do this.

Comment: @oguzhancerit This is a good way if it contains a specific value. But my real situation does not consist of this. Class name can be different. I skipped it my bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question it is unclear what your goal is.
maybe this helps:

```
.main:hover .sub, .main:hover .sub2{
  opacity:1;
}
```

In css (or scss) you can target multiple elements by separating them with a comma.

Comment: it would be nice if i used main:hover all the time but this seems to be the closest. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can select the class begins with a specified value :

```
[class^=sub]
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
.main{
  background:yellow;
  display:inline-block;
}
.sub{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  opacity:.2;
}
.sub2{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  opacity:.2;
}
.main:hover  [class^=sub]{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='sub'></div>
    <div class='sub'></div>
    <div class='sub'></div>
  <div class="sub2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good way if it contains a specific value. But my real situation does not consist of this. Its can be different. I skipped it my bad. Thank you.

Comment: You ask for the shortest way ;), Also you can use a generic class for hover instead of using a lot of .main:hover

Answer (score 1):

According to answers and all comments, maybe you are looking for:

```
.main:hover div {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```css
.main {
    background:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.sub {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    opacity:.3;
}
div.sub2 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    opacity:.3;
}
div.sub3 {
    width:25px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    opacity:.5;
}


.main:hover div {
    opacity:1;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
    <div class='sub'></div>
    <div class='sub'>
      <div class='sub3'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='sub'></div>
    <div class='sub2'></div>
</div>
```

in case you want to target only fist level div's

```
.main:hover > div {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```css
.main {
    background:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.sub {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    opacity:.3;
}
div.sub2 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    opacity:.3;
}
div.sub3 {
    width:25px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    opacity:.5;
}


.main:hover > div {
    opacity:1;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
    <div class='sub'></div>
    <div class='sub'>
      <div class='sub3'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='sub'></div>
    <div class='sub2'></div>
</div>
```

in case all type elements on first level (including p, span, etc.)

```
.main:hover > * {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```css
.main {
    background:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.sub {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    opacity:.3;
}
div.sub2 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    opacity:.3;
}
div.sub3 {
    width:25px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    opacity:.5;
}


.main:hover * {
    opacity:1;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
    <div class='sub'></div>
    <div class='sub'>
      <div class='sub3'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='sub'></div>
    <div class='sub2'></div>
</div>
```